# Need help with a few very confusing sentences, talking about fortune telling and people's fate/ destiny

Tags: meaning, nuances, japanese-to-english, video-games, conversations

**Appreciates if anyone can help me understand the meaning of a few hard parts in this conversation.**

**Context: MC is in an isekai world. MC met a fortune teller while he's looking for a missing girl, she used her fortune telling skill on him and saw a forest - then tell him he should go to this forest to find the missing girl.**

**After he went there together with the fortune teller, they saw an elf girl (not the missing girl who he's been looking for). She said that she want to go inside this forest ,in order to get a special plant and make a medicine for her sick father (also he's the King of her Elf country, I guess she's an elf princess, but right now MC didn't know/ realized that yet.). But there's a dragon inside the forest, preventing her from taking the special plant.**

**MC decided to help her and let the elf girl guide him + the fortune teller to the special plant's location. This means he have to fight the dragon 1st, although he's just a normal human with no special power.**

**Here are the parts that I don't understand much :**

**1/ 世の中はこれ全て、人とのえにし、分けても男女のえにしで成り立っていると聞いたでおす**

**(my guess: "I heard that in this world, everything is being made from the people's fate(?). Even if we divide them into 2 groups(?), the world is still being made of the fate between man and woman."(??)**

and

**2/導いたのはわちきなれど、二人が出会うたのも運命というものじゃろ**

**(my guess: "Though I'm the person who guided him (MC-to this forest), the matter of you and him have met each other, is also a coincident a.k.a fate." (??)**

More context below:

晴哉(MC)「そのドラゴントカゲっていうのは、よっぽど危険なわけ？」

エーリッテ (The Elf girl)「ええ。衛兵も何人も倒れてしまったわ。幸い、お城に解毒剤はあるから、まだ死人は出ていないけど……」

エーリッテ「本当にいいの？　通りがかりのあなたに、こんなことをさせてしまって……」

晴哉「まぁこれも何かの縁だよ」

**夕奈 (The Fortune teller)「そうそう。世の中はこれ全て、人とのえにし、分けても男女のえにしで成り立っていると聞いたでおす」**

**夕奈「導いたのはわちきなれど、二人が出会うたのも運命というものじゃろ」**

Comment: Hum... so in traditional Chinese and Japanese culture, the role of fortunetellers and the concept of fate is very different than in the West. I think you may understand the Japanese just fine, those translations seem good enough.

Comment: in Asia , fortune tellers will help you kill dragons :)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. 世の中はこれ全て、人とのえにし、**分けても**男女のえにしで成り立っていると聞いたでおす

「分けても」 means 「特に」「とりわけ」「中でも」 "especially" "particularly" "among other things". From 明鏡国語辞典:

> わけても【分けても】
> 〘副〙特に。とりわけ。「総じて子供はかわいがったが、**わけても**末娘は[溺愛]{できあい}していた」

---

> 2. 導いたのはわちきなれど、二人が出会うたのも運命というものじゃろ

It roughly means: "Though I guided [the main character], (I suppose) you two were destined to meet."

I think your translation is good.